# Is Single Sign-On preventing me from logging in to new Sandbox?

Tags: single-sign-on

I have Single Sign-On in my org and we prevent regular login. I made a sandbox and my login is failing using myusername.sandboxname

I can't figure out how to log in - I would need SSO, right? But to use SSO, I use my domain, which logs me into Production.

I saw a forum with somebody with this same issue in 2013, and the resolution was to somehow make yourself (admin) an exception to SSO, but I can't figure out how to do that - thoughts? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can override this by using the login parameter:

```
https://mydomain--sbname.my.salesforce.com?login
```

The extra parameter should allow you to log in.

Comment: hm...says it's not found :( 

"<mydomain>--<sbname>.my.salesforce.com’s server IP address could not be found.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN"

Comment: obviously with actual values .... :)

Comment: @NataliePaige You can also try `https://test.salesforce.com/?login`. This works on my sandbox.

Comment: No, ultimately this brings me to production since it's the same issue I've stated -- that when I click "use custom domain" it logs me into prod (because regular sign in is disabled, so I need to use SSO)

Comment: This did worked out for me. Simple trick but saved lot of time for me.!

Answer (score 1):

If you have Delegated Authentication enabled, you can't bypass it with the trick sfdcfox posted. You need to use a user that doesn't have SSO enabled. If you don't have one and have already refreshed your sandbox, you will need to create a user and then refresh or create a new sandbox.

Note: it is good practice to have a "break in case of emergency" user that doesn't have SSO enabled so you can log into your production org in cases where the SSO provider is down.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - as mentioned, I've heard of this solution before, but I don't understand how to make myself exempt from SSO enabled - can you elaborate on how to do this?

Comment: Also, it's disabled from using standard non-SSO sign-on, so would I still be able to log in if I were SSO-exempt in the way you're referring?

Comment: The way we do it is have a permission set that enables SSO. We don't have SSO turned on on any profiles. Every user except the one that you need to manage sandboxes gets the SSO permission set.