# Cannot login to new Sandbox

Tags: single-sign-on, login, partial-sandbox

We have a new Salesforce org. SSO enabled for user login in Production.

I created a new sandbox (Developer Pro)  from Production.

After Sandbox was created, I got an email **Sandbox: xxx is ready to use**

**The email has two URLS

**1st paragraph is**

Your new sandbox "Dev" is ready for use. Click 'some-url' to log in now.

**2nd paragraph is**

Users who were granted access to the sandbox can log in from 'a-different-url' by appending ".dev" to their salesforce.com user logins. For example, if your login in your production account is user@company.domain, then your login for this sandbox is user@company.domain.dev.

I clicked the 1st url entered the username appended with the sandbox name, and entered production password

I clicked the 2nd url entered the username appended with the sandbox name, and entered production password

Neither of this logs me to the sandbox

I did forgot password, got a password reset email with a link. That does not log me to the new sandbox.

**How  can i login to the new sandbox ? What am I missing ?**

Comment: Do you know what is the salesforce instance of this sandbox?

Comment: yes I do. My Domain is enabled in the prod org. When I clicked on forgot password, the link in the email  got starts with this

https://xxxxxx--dev.sandbox.my.salesforce.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After SSO was enabled for the Sandbox and the Salesforce users authorized in Azure, we were able to login with SSO in Sandbox.

I did see a post [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/220223/is-single-sign-on-preventing-me-from-logging-in-to-new-sandbox) which has suggestions that may help others.